# Upload images to apk

Tags: android, image, apk, android-imageview

I want to upload images from gallery to an apk. How can I attach images without web services?

Should I use sqlite for this or content provider ??

Once the image attached I want it to show in image viewer.

Comment: You can keep your images in asset folder. By using AssetManager you can use back your images.

Comment: Haven't you tried by keepin them in your drawable folder ?

Comment: I want images to get upload to my apk dynamically on a click of a button. From a sd card folder to apk.

Comment: What do you mean with "upload to my apk"? Do you want to open phone gallery by a click in a button in your app, then select some image and show it back inside a ImageView inside your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first some things. The images you see in gallery are stored in phone memory or in a SDCard. The images you store in the assets folders inside your app (resources folder in eclipse) are for internal app use, when the apk is build you can't put nothing in there. What you want is associate some image with your app when it is running so there is some ways to do that you just need to pick the fits you.

First you need to open the Image Gallery from your app by Intent, something like this:

```
//Constant to compare result
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
//Intent that call the gallery    
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
//Start another activity that returns a result to yours
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

//Override the callback to get the result for the activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //If everythig ok and a image is selected
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        //Get the image path
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        //Show the image in your ImageView
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
```

Ok now that you have your image you want to decide what to do with it and that's the "upload in my apk" I think you want. The image you have now is in memory phone or SDCard and now you have the path to that image. If you want to duplicate it and store it in your you app you can copy the image to your app private folder, change the image name and store the new path the way you want (sqlite, sharedPrefs, change the name to some logic you can get the image name, etc.) and now the image is "uploaded" to your app. To get the app private folder use `Context.getFilesDir()`. But again you have the image file already, just do what you want with it. And be careful with permissions. The other ways are web services to store images in a server, sqlite to store the image in a database.

Comment: Thanks a lot Labreu for your grt help. Appreciated .